# How to know the directory where the current script lies

Tags: scripting, ammonite

When writing a script, I'd like to know where lies the current script, in order to locate other files.

With a regular Scala script, I know how to do so, but with an Ammonite script I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the standard bang line I normally use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env amm
```

I changed my script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
    exec amm "$0" `dirname "$0"` "$@"
!#

@main
def main(dir: String) {
    print(dir)
}
```

The `dir` argument receives the path where the script lies.  It can be absolute or relative.

If we always desire an absolute path:

```
#!/bin/bash
    exec amm "$0" $(cd `dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"` && pwd) "$@"
!#
```

Answer (score 2):

it's been a long time since the question but you can get directory for script file like this in current Ammonite:

```scala
val src: String = sourcecode.File()
val rootDir: Path = os.Path(src) / os.up
```

Comment: Confirmed that it works.  Your solution is better than mine, because it also works for Windows.